# Absolute Positioning (Values to use) in CSS

Tags: css

How do you know what numbers to use for top & left for absolute positioning?

Comment: Please elaborate on your question. What are you asking?

Comment: I'm not sure why people are down-voting this, it's a valid question.  This is especially valid for someone who is just starting out.

Comment: It is a bad question because it shows no research value. This is a question that could be found with a google search

Comment: Possibly but also she could have found it explaining what it is but she had no idea in her situation how to determine what numbers to use.

Comment: Apart from the no research effort, the question lacks context. You should be more specific, presenting a specific use case or such. Please read the [FAQ - What kind of questions can I ask here?](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mainly you keep changing the numbers until it is what you want.  You can set it and refresh and repeat that until you get the desired result.

Also you can view developer tools (such as in Chrome right-click and inspect element).  You can change those numbers and see it update live on the page.  You can then copy the correct number back to your CSS file.

Comment: Ah alright, thanks! I thought you had to use a program or something xD

Comment: No worries, be sure to accept this answer as correct if this answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

- The parent element must be position:relative
- The child element must be position:absolute

**left** is the value that separates the child element of the internal left border of the parent element.

**top** is the value that separates the child element of the inner upper border of the parent element.

Comment: I think you forgot right and bottom :-)

Comment: Also, `fixed` and `absolute` positions also reset descendant elements' absolute positioning (as @Vector answered, anything besides `static` does).

Comment: @FlorianMargaine Yes, but the question is "How do you know what numbers to use for top & left for absolute positioning?"